# Why am I getting the following output?

Tags: c++

I have this very simple c++ program. It's been years that I did some C++ so I thought I might give it a spin one more time. But I am amazed by the output I am getting. It was supposed to be a simple program and it's causing me some headaches already.

```
//2.cpp
//This program asks for the radius of the circle and
//prints the area of that circle 

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* area(char* radius[], int size)
{
        int* pointer;
        int areas[size];
        pointer = areas;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                areas[i] = 3.1416*atoi(radius[i])*atoi(radius[i]);
        }
        return pointer;
}
void print(char* radius[], int* area1, int size)
{
        std::cout<<area1[2]<<std::endl; //This prints fine
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                std::cout << area1[i]; //This doesn't
                std::cout << "Area for " << radius[i] << " is: " << area1[i] << std::endl;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        if(argc > 1)
        {
                print(&argv[1],area(&argv[1],argc-1),argc-1);
        }
        else
        {
            //Please ignore this
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
./a.out 1 4 2 7 8
```

Output:-

```
12
134520896
Area for 1 is: 134520896
10
Area for 4 is: 10
-1217419175
Area for 2 is: -1217419175
-1217056780
Area for 7 is: -1217056780
-1217056780
Area for 8 is: -1217056780
```

Comment: `int areas[size];` is not legal standard C++.

Comment: ... and that array gets destroyed as soon as its function returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `areas` array has automatic storage duration and goes out of scope once `area` returns; then dereferencing `pointer` is undefined behavior. Please use C++ idioms like `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of C pointers.

Here is an improved (but still not optimal) version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>

std::vector<double> area(const std::vector<double>& radius)
{
  std::vector<double> areas(radius.size());
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < radius.size(); i++) {
    areas[i] = 3.1416 * radius[i] * radius[i];
  }
  return areas;
}

void print(const std::vector<double>& radius, const std::vector<double>& area)
{
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < radius.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << area[i]; //This doesn't
    std::cout << "Area for " << radius[i] << " is: " << area[i] << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1) {
    std::vector<double> radii;
    radii.reserve(argc - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      radii.push_back(std::atof(argv[i]));
    }
    print(radii, area(radii));
  }
}
```

Unfortunately compilers often cannot detect such errors. Use a tool like Valgrind to find them. For example, running your original code through Valgrind produces many errors for me:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out 1 4 2 7 8
==18488== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18488== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18488== Using Valgrind-3.8.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18488== Command: ./a.out 1 4 2 7 8
==18488== 
==18488== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18488==    at 0x4EC5D16: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x4EC5F4C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x4EC8E45: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x400A01: print(char**, int*, int) (in /tmp/a.out)
==18488==    by 0x400B0E: main (in /tmp/a.out)
==18488== 
==18488== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==18488==    at 0x4EBB133: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x4EC5D37: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x4EC5F4C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x4EC8E45: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==18488==    by 0x400A01: print(char**, int*, int) (in /tmp/a.out)
==18488==    by 0x400B0E: main (in /tmp/a.out)
[…]
```

while my version produces no errors.

Comment: Thank you so so much for taking your time and trying to figure out the solution. Also, many thanks for suggesting Valgrind.

Answer (score 3):

`return pointer;` - You are returning a pointer to a local variable, which is allocated on the stack and goes out of scope when you exit from the function.

Unfortunately your compiler was not clever enough to recognise this, for example with `gcc` I have to return `areas` to get a warning: `warning: address of local variable ‘areas’ returned`

Comment: I realize that immediately when @Philipp mentioned that it was out of scope. I really need a lot of practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting anew with C++ I think you should have a look at the new standard, **C++11**. Start out at the wikipedia page. This is my version of your code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<double> area(const std::vector<double> & radii ) {
  std::vector<double> areas(radii.size());
  std::transform (radii.begin(), radii.end(), areas.begin(),
          [](const double &r){ return 3.15159*r*r; } );
  return areas;
}

void printit(const std::vector<double> &r, const std::vector<double> &a) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "Area for " << r.at(i) << " is: " << a.at(i) << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<double> r(argc-1);
  std::transform (argv+1, argv+argc,r.begin(),
           [](const std::string &r){ return stod(r); } );
  auto areas=area(r);
  printit(r,areas);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to invalid memory from this function.

```
int* area(char* radius[], int size)
{
        int* pointer;
        int areas[size];
        pointer = areas;

        // ...

        return pointer;
}
```

`int areas[size]` only exists for the duration of this function.  You are returning a pointer to undefined memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `areas` is an integer but you put a float into it..

When calculating the radius that gives out a result that might be different from the right one!

`areas[i] = 3.1416*atoi(radius[i])*atoi(radius[i]);`

Comment: just wrong. You can assign a float to an integer. It's perfectly legal.

Comment: It is legal to put an float into an integer.. ( Yeah I accept my mistake ).. But when calculating the radius that gives out a result that might be different from the right one!

Comment: Well, considering Pi is irrational and he's passing int values as radius, a float can't store the "right result" either.

Answer (score 0):

Radius is a pointer to the string "1" but you are stepping through argc values, which is wrong.

Comment: Why is stepping through `argv` values wrong?  (I assume you meant `argv`.)